# How to find number of character positions in strings with Unicode combining sequences?

Tags: python, string, unicode

```
python -v:  Python 3.8.10

uname -a: Linux ray-desktop 5.11.0-40-generic
          #44~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 26 18:07:44 UTC 2021
          x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

>>> len("Spinal")
6
>>> len("Spial")
6
>>> len("Spin̈al")
7
```

This is correctly counting the Unicode green blob as a single character, but the Unicode combining sequence that produces the umlaut-n gets counted as two characters.

How should one handle such things when trying to make monospaced text columns line up?

Comment: Using `unicodedata.normalize()` with form "NFC" might help - at least in cases where there is a single-character equivalent to the combining sequences.